# How to merge cells in same column, apply rowspan?

Tags: jasper-reports

In jrxml design for my report, I have a column in my detail section that is printing same thing for a specific group. For Example, if i have a country column USA and the next column contains its states. Country USA repeats for each entry . So i need to merge the country cells has USA value. I need to merge all the cells of column has same value and should display it as a single cell and it should align its text vertically and horizontally center. Anybody help me how can i achieve this by using jrxml?

Everything is in the Detail band.

I am working to get a report like in the below picture

[image]

---

*UPDATED*:

From Peter's answer I have one doubt, if my xml is like:

```
<report>
   <row1>
    <country>INDIA</country>
    <state>Haryana</state>
   </row1>
   <row2>
    <country>INDIA</country>
    <state>Punjab</state>
   </row2>
   <row3>
     <country>INDIA</country>
     <state>Maharashtra</state>
   </row3>
</report>
```

How can I create the report if my xml is like above?

Comment: grouping is used to group rowwise right. How to use with column?

Comment: are you using the jr:table component or working directly in the detail band.. Can you pass some relevant jrxml, screen shot current output with desired result.

Comment: I am working directly in detail band. Is there any control to show the merged cells for country values like India, USA. Could you  please check the updated post.

Comment: I have included an example, with screen shots... if text vertically aligned at top you can achieve fairly easy, if you need  text vertically aligned at center you need to use a subreport and structure your datasource as example below.

Comment: I suggest you create another question for you new edit, but I would say that you can not create a datasource on this xml since row1 changes to row2 (we can't define any XPath that gives us all the rows)..... You need to elaborate the xml in java and turn it in to something useful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can fairly easy achieve **text vertically aligned at top** by using `isPrintRepeatedValues="false"`, setting borders correctly (only top, using empty cell with only left, adding line to `columnFooter`).

[image: Top alignment result]

To achieve **"text vertically aligned at center"** use a subreport for the other columns and set `stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight"` on your rowspan column.

Note you need in this case change your datasource (main report, country by country, subreport all states relative to country)

[image: Align center]

**EDIT**: Comment: *This not works in detail band. Petter – @Tinoy Malayil*.

I include a runnable example for text vertically aligned at center:

**Datasource** xml:

```
<report>
    <country>
        <name>INDIA</name>
        <states>
            <state>Haryana</state>
            <state>Punjab</state>
            <state>Maharashtra</state>
            <state>Karnataka</state>
            <state>TamilNadu</state>
        </states>
    </country>
    <country>
        <name>USA</name>
        <states>
            <state>Alabama</state>
            <state>Washington</state>
            <state>Alaska</state>
            <state>Texas</state>
        </states>
    </country>
</report>
```

**Main report:**, `country.jrxml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Country" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="30" bottomMargin="30" uuid="dbc44bea-4f8e-4072-9c94-8442f3093aa0">
<parameter name="SUBREPORT_DIR" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
    <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["C:\\fullPath\\to\\Your\\subreport\\"]]></defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>
<queryString language="xPath">
    <![CDATA[report/country]]>
</queryString>
<field name="name" class="java.lang.String">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[name]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<background>
    <band/>
</background>
<columnHeader>
    <band height="20">
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="177" height="20" uuid="d4eb7868-2f74-4713-abca-a176c47927e1"/>
            <box>
                <pen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                <topPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                <leftPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                <rightPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
            </box>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
            <text><![CDATA[COUNTRY]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="177" y="0" width="200" height="20" uuid="98cbcff7-6b24-43bd-a2df-39cc07e56487"/>
            <box>
                <pen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                <topPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                <leftPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                <rightPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
            </box>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
            <text><![CDATA[STATE]]></text>
        </staticText>
    </band>
</columnHeader>
<detail>
    <band height="20">
        <textField>
            <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" x="0" y="0" width="177" height="20" uuid="1bbab3e7-f8a3-48c9-b28e-2a6d2a68b755"/>
            <box topPadding="0" leftPadding="0">
                <pen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                <topPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                <leftPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                <rightPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
            </box>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{name}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <subreport>
            <reportElement x="177" y="0" width="200" height="20" uuid="6314908a-006d-4a5b-9137-a056eb205529"/>
            <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRXmlDataSource)$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}).subDataSource("/country/states/state")]]></dataSourceExpression>
            <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR} + "country_subreport.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
        </subreport>
    </band>
  </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

**subreport**, `country_subreport.jrxml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="country_subreport" language="java" pageWidth="200" pageHeight="500" columnWidth="200" leftMargin="0" rightMargin="0" topMargin="0" bottomMargin="0" uuid="c9795fb7-39e0-4aa6-8926-2f019c4af84e">
<property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
<property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
<property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
<queryString language="xPath">
    <![CDATA[/report/country/states/state]]>
</queryString>
<field name="state" class="java.lang.String">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[child::text()]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<detail>
    <band height="20" splitType="Stretch">
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="200" height="20" uuid="dc0a9dda-b940-4752-ad91-31420c4ce729"/>
            <box topPadding="2" leftPadding="2">
                <pen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                <topPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                <leftPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                <rightPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
            </box>
            <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{state}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
    </band>
</detail>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is really helpful. Using sub report i can achieve the objective.

Comment: Hi Peter I have one another doubt. If your xml input is like :           `<report>
    <row1>
        <country>INDIA</country>
            <state>Haryana</state>
            <state>Punjab</state>
            <state>Maharashtra</state>
            <state>Karnataka</state>
            <state>TamilNadu</state>
        </states>
    </country>
    <country>
        <name>USA</name>
        <states>
            <state>Alabama</state>
            <state>Washington</state>
            <state>Alaska</state>
            <state>Texas</state>
        </states>
    </country>
</report>`

Comment: @TinoyMalayil I have commented under the question, that xml is not useful (the row tag changes from row1 to row2)... you need to parse it and turn it into something useful for jasper report....

Comment: @PetterFriberg Hi Peter, do you know is it possible to achieve this with table component? Thanks

Comment: what is the left cell is higher than right one? How to stretch the subreport vertically?

Comment: @EkaterinaIvanovaiceja.net, you can stretch the su report and external borders outside, but ti have variable row height would be very complex, if not impossible